# How to make the Windows 10 and Windows 11 experience like Mac

Tags: windows-10, macos

Make the Windows 10 and Windows 11 experience like Mac:

1. Modifier keys <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> mapping
2. Make use of touchpads
3. Capslock for switching language
4. Close windows on the left side

Comment: The downvotes mean for no reason. These are legitimate points that could be VERY relevant for a user that is running windows under on a Macintosh computer, like what Bootcamp and Parallels do!

Answer (score 5):

For <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, etc.

[Use PowerToys to remap the keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/):

[image]

#### For touchpads

[image]

Check for a precision touchpad

- Open Settings on Windows 10.
- Go to the Devices menu.
- Click on Touchpad.
- Choose the type of touch gesture and add actions.

The precision touchpad on Windows 10 supports multiple gestures, with two, three, and four-finger support. Read further to find out more about these gestures.

#### Configure Two-finger Gestures

The one-finger gesture for Windows 10 trackpad gestures are pretty standard. You can click, hold, and drag. At the same time, the two-finger touchpad gestures on Windows 10 is customizable. You can get Mac-like up and down scrolling in Windows 10 with two-finger gestures.

#### Two finger Gestures in Windows 10 Precision Touchpad

You get options such as Tap with two fingers to right-click under the sensitivity drop-down menu. Under Scroll and zoom, you can enable/disable the two-finger scrolling gesture, adjust the scroll direction, and enable/disable Pinch to zoom.

[image]

#### Configure Three and Four-finger Gestures

By default, the three-finger gesture on Windows is set to *switch* applications and show the desktop. The four-finger gesture on Windows is set to switch desktops and show desktop. You can now change and set a custom action for these gestures, which are almost similar to MacBook trackpad gestures.

#### Three finger Gestures for Precision Touchpad in Windows 10

The following are some of the gesture actions for three and four-finger

[image]

[For more information](https://mashtips.com/windows-10-touchpad-gestures/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20get%20Mac-like%20up%20and%20down%20scrolling,the%20scroll%20direction%2C%20and%20enable%2Fdisable%20Pinch%20to%20zoom.)

Comment: It looks like you have used some default JPEG encoding for the screenshots somewhere in that process (making them ***unnecessarily*** blurred). Can you please use the crisp (lossless) PNG format all the way through instead?